# TYPO3 7.6.12 Call to a member function getPage_noCheck() on string

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typolink

I don't know why my Extension throws this error. Because other extensions like *dd_googlesitemap* use it in same way as me and this extension do not throw this error.

What am I doing wrong with my `$pageId` param:

```
/**
 * Creates a link to a single page
 *
 * @param   array   $pageId Page ID
 * @return  string  Full URL of the page including host name (escaped)
 */
protected function getPageLink($pageId) {
    $conf = array(
        'parameter' => $pageId,
        'returnLast' => 'url',
    );

    $link = htmlspecialchars($this->cObj->typoLink('', $conf));
    return GeneralUtility::locationHeaderUrl($link);
}
```

And this is the error output:

```
Call to a member function getPage_noCheck() on string
```

It is the method `detectLinkTypeFromLinkParameter` on *line 6364*.

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears because the `$GLOBAL['TSFE']` isn´t initialized at the time I try to use it. After initialization it throws no more errors and works well.

**Update:**
For those who are still searching for this solution and still using typo3 7.6: 
Search for the method ***initTSFE*** where it is defined on line 208 (this is the method to init the "TSFE") and where it is initialized on line 94 before ***getPageLink*** method
Here the link to the file https://ideone.com/f4TGMm

Comment: how did you inizialize `$GLOBAL['TSFE']`?

Answer (score 0):

can you cast your pageUid to `int` like this

```
$conf = array(
    'parameter' => (int)$pageId,
    'returnLast' => 'url',
);
```

Comment: i already did it. it is the method ```detectLinkTypeFromLinkParameter``` which is converts it back to string.